# How to get different parameter types per Joomla ACL ?

Tags: joomla

Right now you can only set 'Allowed', 'Inherited' and 'Prohibited' per Joomla ACL. That's fine but far from complete. Consider the simple case you want to set a string per ACL, like 'allowed upload extensions'. There seems little or no information about.

Any ideas on this ? Its seems even more complicated when you want to register 'dynamic' parameters on the fly, so all this XML based persistence model you have in Joomla will fall a part as well...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This would be wrong, and a nightmare to debug (imagine guiding users when they start calling because they can't do something, and you have no idea where to look).

If you want your component to have more user-configurable actions, you can define some params in the config, where you set the list of extensions allowed in a custom action level, such as "extensions.safe", then assign that. You can create as many as you want. Find more info [here](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Adding_ACL)

Unless you're proposing that existing components take into consideration arbitrarily defined dynamic parameters, it's hard to see how it could work.